# Problems coloring cells in a table

Tags: tables, color

I am facing problems with coloring cells in my table. I am using sharelatex and the documentclass report. The pictures shows my code, and how it is displayed. It just prints out the text instead of coloring the cells. Does anybody know what is wrong and how to fix the problem?

The Code:

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{colortbl}

\begin{table}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
    & CFRP & Aluminum & Polyurethane BM5172 & Steel alloy\\
    \hline
    \hline
    Density [g/cm$^3$] & \cellcolor{yellow}1.5 & 2.7-2.8 & 1.2 & 7.75-8.05
    \cite{Steel_density}\\
    \hline
    Compressive strength [MPa] & 570 \cite{CFRP_properties} & 30-280
    \cite{Alu_comp} & 65 & 200-2100 \cite{Steel_comp}\\
    \hline
    Ease of machining & & & &
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Material choice}
    \label{tab:Material_choice}
\end{table}
```

[image: display]

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]! Please post your code, not a picture of the code.  Also make sure that it is compilable.  What you post has no `\documntclass` nor any `\begin{document}`.

Comment: You should place your `\usepackage{}` calls before specifying `\begin{document}`.

Comment: Documentclass and beginning of document is written at the beginning of the document. Like this:"\documentclass[../main.tex]{subfiles}
\begin{document} " The subfiles are imported into the main file, which works fine.

Comment: Using \usepackage{} before \begin{document} did not make any difference to the results.

Comment: When using the `subfiles` package, you probably have to include the needed packages in the preamble of your main file.

Comment: @Atle, please provide code in form of small but complete code beginning  with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. in preamble had to be loaded only packages relevant to your problem and page layout. without this we are on field of guessing which not enable to help you ...

Comment: Sorry to take your time guys, but it worked when I created a completely new document and imported all packages (\usepackage{}) before \begin{document}. It did not work when I imported new packages, \usepackage{colortbl}, inside the subfile... Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me it compiles normally, after I've completed  your code. However I think you don't have to reinvent the wheel and define a command for the common formatting of column heads: the `makecell` package already offers a `\thead` command, and it lets you break lines in standard cells:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{tabularx, float, makecell}
\renewcommand{\theadfont}{\normalsize\itshape\bfseries}

\usepackage[table, svgnames, x11names]{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{c|c|c|c|c}
 & \thead{CFRP} & \thead{Aluminum} & \thead{Polyurethane\\ BM5172} & \thead{Steel alloy}\\
\hline
\hline
Density [g/cm$^3$] & \cellcolor{yellow}1.5 & 2.7-2.8 & 1.2 & 7.75-8.05
\cite{Steel_density}\\
\hline
Compressive strength [MPa] & 570 \cite{CFRP_properties} & 30-280
\cite{Alu_comp} & 65 & 200-2100 \cite{Steel_comp}\\
\hline
Ease of machining & & & &
\end{tabular}
\caption{Material choice}
\label{tab:Material_choice}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]